# httpheaders not set in angular 9 get?

Tags: angular, http, angular9

In Angular 9

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
.set('Authorization', this.getToken());   
return this.httpClient.get(url,{headers:headers}).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

can't connect httpheaders. headers not attached with get post put delete call why ?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't connect httpHeaders"? 
Can you show the request in the developer console?

Comment: Also, setting a content-type on a get request, which doesn't have a content, doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct syntax :

```
const httpOptions = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': this.getToken()
});
this.httpClient.get(url, httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:-

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
headers=headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
headers=headers.set('Authorization', this.getToken());   
return this.httpClient.get(url,{headers:headers}).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

Since httpheader and httpparams are kinda immutable in nature so assiging it to the returned object should work.